# Why wont ID number jump to the next one

Tags: jquery

There is a one section of orders page where users can add new fields to add new products. The problem here is, every time user adds new fields, new fields should have names as PRODUCTNAME1, PRODUCTNAME2, PRODUCTNAME3, and so on. Right now, every new field added has 1 value. Its stuck there. I hope I made some sense.

```
$('#AddProduct').click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var adding = $(+(i++)+'<div class="row'+(i)+'"><div class="column width50"><input type="text" id="PRODUCTNAME" name="PRODUCTNAME'+(i)+'" value="" class="width98" /><input type="hidden" class="PRODUCTID" name="PRODUCTID" /><input type="hidden" class="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE'+(i)+'" value="" /><input type="hidden" class="TOTALPRICE" name="TOTALPRICE'+(i)+'" value="" /><small>Search Products</small></div><div class="column width20"><input type="text" class="UNITQUANTITY" name="UNITQUANTITY'+(i)+'" value="1" class="width98" /><small>Quantity</small></div><div class="column width30"><span class="prices">Unit Price:<span class="UNITPRICE"></span><br />Total Price:<span class="TOTALPRICE"></span><br /><a href="#" id="RemoveProduct(".row'+(i)+'");">Remove</a></span></div>');    
    $('#OrderProducts').append(adding);

    adding.find("#PRODUCTNAME").autocomplete("orders.cs.asp?Process=ListProducts", {
        selectFirst: false
    }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
        if (data) {
            adding.find(".UNITPRICE").val(data[1]);
            adding.find(".UNITPRICE").html(data[1]);
            adding.find(".PRODUCTID").val(data[2]);
            adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").val(data[1] * $('.UNITQUANTITY').val()); 
            adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").html(data[1] * $('.UNITQUANTITY').val()); 
        }
    });

    adding.find(".UNITQUANTITY").change(function()
    {
        adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").val(adding.find(".UNITPRICE").val() * adding.find(".UNITQUANTITY").val()); 
        adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").html(adding.find(".UNITPRICE").val() * adding.find(".UNITQUANTITY").val()); 
    });


    return false;
});
```

Comment: By the way, something seems not right about this HTML:
`<div class="row'+(i)`.  You probably don't want the row number being appended to the class name. Perhaps you should either change 'class' to 'id', or not append `i` to the class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is reset to 0 every time `$('#AddProduct').click()` is called; I don't think that's what you want. You would need `i` to be declared outside of the function that's passed into `$('#AddProduct').click()`. One way to do this would be through a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Working_with_Closures).

(Note: I haven't tested this.)

```
var onClick = (function() {
    var i = 0;
    return (function () {
        var adding = $(+(i++)+'<div class="row'+(i)+'"><div class="column width50"><input type="text" id="PRODUCTNAME" name="PRODUCTNAME'+(i)+'" value="" class="width98" /><input type="hidden" class="PRODUCTID" name="PRODUCTID" /><input type="hidden" class="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE'+(i)+'" value="" /><input type="hidden" class="TOTALPRICE" name="TOTALPRICE'+(i)+'" value="" /><small>Search Products</small></div><div class="column width20"><input type="text" class="UNITQUANTITY" name="UNITQUANTITY'+(i)+'" value="1" class="width98" /><small>Quantity</small></div><div class="column width30"><span class="prices">Unit Price:<span class="UNITPRICE"></span><br />Total Price:<span class="TOTALPRICE"></span><br /><a href="#" id="RemoveProduct(".row'+(i)+'");">Remove</a></span></div>');    

        $('#OrderProducts').append(adding);

        adding.find("#PRODUCTNAME").autocomplete("orders.cs.asp?Process=ListProducts", {
            selectFirst: false
        }).result(function(event, data, formatted) {
            if (data) {
                adding.find(".UNITPRICE").val(data[1]);
                adding.find(".UNITPRICE").html(data[1]);
                adding.find(".PRODUCTID").val(data[2]);
                adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").val(data[1] * $('.UNITQUANTITY').val()); 
                adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").html(data[1] * $('.UNITQUANTITY').val()); 
            }
        });

        adding.find(".UNITQUANTITY").change(function()
        {
            adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").val(adding.find(".UNITPRICE").val() * adding.find(".UNITQUANTITY").val()); 
            adding.find(".TOTALPRICE").html(adding.find(".UNITPRICE").val() * adding.find(".UNITQUANTITY").val()); 
        });

        return false;
    });
})();

$('#AddProduct').click(onClick);
```

Comment: Yep.  When i is inside the function, it gets set to 0 and then incremented every time the function is called.

Comment: Yes. I haven't tested it, but I did see that I hadn't gotten the syntax right. I've updated the answer, and I *think* I got it right this time.

Comment: Yes its right. Thank you so much. I still dont understand why i inside function ... off never you mind, thank you very much again, I should do some thinking now.

Answer (score 1):

This code needs a lot of work. I do want to make just one suggestion though: rather than having a massive escaped HTML string within a javascript variable, you should just create a template DOM element and clone it when you need a copy of it:

```
$("#AddProduct").click(function(){
  var newProd = $("#template").clone().removeAttr("id").removeAttr("style");
  /* change values, then add to the DOM */
  $("#OrderProducts").append(newProd);
});
```

--

```
<div class="row1" id="template" style="display:none" >
  <div class="column width50">
    <input type="text" id="PRODUCTNAME" name="PRODUCTNAME1" value="" class="width98" />
    <input type="hidden" class="PRODUCTID" name="PRODUCTID" />
    <input type="hidden" class="UNITPRICE" name="UNITPRICE1" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" class="TOTALPRICE" name="TOTALPRICE1" value="" />
    <small>Search Products</small>
  </div>
  <div class="column width20">
    <input type="text" class="UNITQUANTITY" name="UNITQUANTITY1" value="1" class="width98" />
    <small>Quantity</small>
  </div>
  <div class="column width30">
    <span class="prices">
      Unit Price:<span class="UNITPRICE"></span><br />
      Total Price:<span class="TOTALPRICE"></span><br />
      <a href="#" id="RemoveProduct1">Remove</a>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this bit of code, for example:

```
'<input type="text" id="PRODUCTNAME" name="PRODUCTNAME'+(i)+'"
    value="" class="width98" />'
```

You're giving each input a different name, but the same ID. Contrary to what Microsoft would have you think, the two are not interchangeable.